# Bind tmux prefix to section symbol §

Tags: osx, zsh, tmux

I usually use the backtick key as my prefix, but this keyboard has the section/stanza symbol § where the backtick usually (at least, for me in the UK) is.

If I bind to this key, quoted or unquoted, tmux complains that it's an invalid symbol.

If I run `cat` and press the `§` key, it prints `§`.

I'm on Mac, using Terminal.app, and if I open the "key/modifier/action" preferences (i.e. to set § key + no modifier = send some text other than `§`, even `C-b` say) and press `§` while in the 'key' drop-down it selects 'arrow-left', as if that's what I'd pressed.

However if I press it in the 'send text' box, it writes `§` whereas 'arrow-left' is escaped for navigation, and writes nothing (and is mapped to `\033[1;5D`).

I think maybe its code is just close to arrow-left, hence it selects that in the finite choice drop-down. But since it `cat`s to 'itself' I'm not sure how else to make tmux recognise it?

Answer (score 2):

Ah - I didn't intend to answer my own, but I just found a good enough solution for me.

Since I never need the `§` key anyway, and I use backticks a fair bit - marking code here for example! - I just used '[Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)' (download .dmg from linked page, or `brew cask install karabiner`) to remap that key.

Then simply used my standard `.tmux.conf` with backtick prefix.

Not exactly an answer, but if like me you don't need (or care about it being in that position) `§` anyway, it works.

Comment: Probably the best you can do; `tmux` requires the prefix to be a single ASCII character, which § is not.